# For in twig with include

Tags: for-loop, foreach, include, twig, cycle

I need do a cycle for with an include directive in twig but the template twig will not repeat. This is a snippet of my code:

```
...
{% for object in objects %}
   {% include 'template.html.twig' with {'object':object} %}
{% endfor %}
...
```

Only the first object is received, but the rest of the objects I need are not received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with TWIG, the error was in JQUERY. The FOR-LOOP is valid with an INCLUDE inside.

TEMPLATE TWIG 1: print n modals with different contents

```
...
{% for object in objects %}
   {% include 'template2.html.twig' with {'object':object} %}
   <button type="button" class="btn-primary" title="modal-view" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-{{object['id_object']}}">View</button>
{% endfor %}
...
```

TEMPLATE TWIG 2: modal bootstrap

```
...
<div id="modal-{{object['id_object']}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <h2 class="modal-title">{{object['title']}}</h2>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                 <p>{{object['content']}}</p>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: You need to include relevant code in order for us to give you a good answer. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried anything like that before, but I wonder if this might work or not:

```
{% include 'template.html.twig' with {'objects':objects} %}
```

In order words don't put that in the for loop, and pass `objects` directly to your included template, and then within the `template.html.twig` you can also use the `objects` array directly.

Again, I'm not sure if this will work; maybe you can try it, or maybe you need something different.

Comment: Thanks, in that case, if it works, but I would have to walk the matrix again. In the twig template I have the design of a modal, but this has changes like the name of the object and description of the object.